# How to check for EOF in Python?

Tags: python, eof

How do I check for EOF in Python? I found a bug in my code where the last block of text after the separator isn't added to the return list. Or maybe there's a better way of expressing this function?

Here's my code:

```
def get_text_blocks(filename):
    text_blocks = []
    text_block = StringIO.StringIO()
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            text_block.write(line)
            print line
            if line.startswith('-- -'):
                text_blocks.append(text_block.getvalue())
                text_block.close()
                text_block = StringIO.StringIO()
    return text_blocks
```

Comment: Try now, fixed my function x2 =(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find it easier to solve this using [itertools.groupby](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).

```
def get_text_blocks(filename):
    import itertools
    with open(filename,'r') as f:
        groups = itertools.groupby(f, lambda line:line.startswith('-- -'))
        return [''.join(lines) for is_separator, lines in groups if not is_separator]
```

Another alternative is to use a [regular expression](http://www.amk.ca/python/howto/regex/) to match the separators:

```
def get_text_blocks(filename):
    import re
    seperator = re.compile('^-- -.*', re.M)
    with open(filename,'r') as f:
        return re.split(seperator, f.read())
```

Comment: Interesting answers Mark. I didn't know about itertools, thanks.

Comment: +1 For RegEx version, the itertools version is slightly cryptic.

Comment: I tried the itertools version on the ineractive interpreter and it returns an empty string. lines seems to be an itertools._grouper object

Comment: It's unlikely to return an empty string. It always returns a list. You must have a copy/paste error.

Comment: Sorry my bad, an empty list I mean.

Comment: Well all I can say is that it works here for the files I tested it on. Maybe you gave it an empty file, or a file where every line was a separator? I can't really explain it without more details. You can just use the regex method (the second alternative) if you can't get the first working (though I suspect that whatever you are doing wrong with the first method will also cause problems with the second).

Comment: You're right the file object is empty because I've iterated through it, may bad again. Anyway thank you for itertools :)

Answer (score 1):

The end-of-file condition holds as soon as the `for` statement terminates -- that seems the simplest way to minorly fix this code (you can extract `text_block.getvalue()` at the end if you want to check it's not empty before appending it).

Comment: Thanks Alex! My dirty solution was to add text_blocks.append(text_block.getvalue()) and text_block.close() below the for block. It works but it's not DRY :/

Answer (score 1):

This is the standard problem with emitting buffers.

You don't detect EOF -- that's needless.  You write the last buffer.

```
def get_text_blocks(filename):
    text_blocks = []
    text_block = StringIO.StringIO()
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            text_block.write(line)
            print line
            if line.startswith('-- -'):
                text_blocks.append(text_block.getvalue())
                text_block.close()
                text_block = StringIO.StringIO()
         ### At this moment, you are at EOF
         if len(text_block) > 0:
             text_blocks.append( text_block.getvalue() )
         ### Now your final block (if any) is appended.
    return text_blocks
```

Answer (score -1):

Why do you need StringIO here?

```
def get_text_blocks(filename):
    text_blocks = [""]
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            if line.startswith('-- -'):
                text_blocks.append(line)
            else: text_blocks[-1] += line          
    return text_blocks
```

EDIT: Fixed the function, other suggestions might be better, just wanted to write a function similar to the original one.

EDIT: Assumed the file starts with "-- -", by adding empty string to the list you can "fix" the IndexError or you could use this one:

```
def get_text_blocks(filename):
    text_blocks = []
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            if line.startswith('-- -'):
                text_blocks.append(line)
            else:
                if len(text_blocks) != 0:
                    text_blocks[-1] += line          
    return text_blocks
```

But both versions look a bit ugly to me, the reg-ex version is much more cleaner.

Comment: That still misses the last block.

Comment: Could you please provide test input data?

Comment: @maiku the test input data is a SQL dump by phpMyAdmin. I need to separate the text in blocks separated by a line that starts with -- -...

Comment: Yea, I got it now, misunderstood the task.

Comment: Now I get 'IndexError: list index out of range'

Comment: Ehh ... I should just go sleep instead of surfing SO =(

Comment: @Maiku don't give up, you can do it (maybe tomorrow) :)

Answer (score -2):

This is a fast way to see if you have an empty file:

```
if f.read(1) == '': 
 print "EOF"
 f.close()
```

Comment: No, because there is no space between the ''. I tested this on a file with just a space, and it didn't detect that the file was empty.

Comment: If a file contains a space it isn't empty.

Comment: AndroidDebaser: this is an incomplete answer. `f.read(1)` will consume 1 character (your single space) so it needs to be in a loop, something like `while f.read(1) != '':` would iterate until there is nothing left to iterate on.